# Area based authentication using OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, owin-middleware

I am developing an MVC5 web application. This application has 2 areas, 'SU' and ''App'. Each area should be authenticated independently. Each area also have their own login pages.
I am using [OWIN](http://owin.org/) for authenticating users.
Now the issue is, I am unable set owin `CookieAuthenticationOptions` `LoginPath` based on the area the user is requesting.
For example, if user request `http://example.com/su/reports/dashboard`, I should be able to redirect them to `http://example.com/su/auth/login`
Likewise, for 'App' area, if user request `http://example.com/app/history/dashboard`, I should be able to redirect them to `http://example.com/app/auth/login`

I would like to avoid Custom Attribute and hence tried following code but it is always redirecting to root login path i.e., `http://example.com/auth/login`

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            string loginPath = "/auth/login";
            string areaName = string.Empty;
            if (url.ToLower().Contains("/su/"))
            {
                areaName = "SU";
                loginPath = "/su/auth/login"; 
            }
            if (url.ToLower().Contains("/app/"))
            {
                areaName = "APP";
                loginPath = "/app/auth/login";
            }
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie" + areaName,
                LoginPath = new PathString(loginPath)
            });
        }
}
```

Am I following right approach or is there any other way to achieve the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath` property is set once on startup. In order to use different URL based on request, you could use either custom implementation of `ICookieAuthenticationProvider` set through `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Provider` or just set your custom action for `OnApplyRedirect` in built-in `CookieAuthenticationProvider`. Second option is simpler and seems enough for your case.

Here is a sample code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider { OnApplyRedirect = OnApplyRedirect }
});

public static void OnApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
{
    var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

    string redirectUrl = "/auth/login";
    if (url.ToLower().Contains("/su/"))
    {
        redirectUrl = "/su/auth/login";
    }
    else if (url.ToLower().Contains("/app/"))
    {
        redirectUrl = "/app/auth/login";
    }

    context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```